# jquery toppanel show and hide

Tags: jquery, hide, panel, show

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/X9Vn4/50/) is the code for showing and hiding the top panel :

It works fine, but when I implement it on a website is not working properly.
Check out this [link](http://outboxvision.com/gallery/) to see how it works.
Any suggestions?

Comment: "it is not working properly" is not good enough. How is it not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your webpage HTML:

```
<div id="panel"> 
     <div id="open">Open</div> 
     <div id="close">Close</div> 
</div>
```

you have everything inside panel, when you do:

```
$("#close").hover(function(){
     $("div#panel").slideUp("slow");
     if(autoTimer) clearTimeout(autoTimer);
     autoTimer = null;
});
```

You hide everything inside panel, including the close and open.

Answer (score 0):

In your website the `panel` div contains everything. So when you hide/slideToggle panel div it is showing/hiding everything. Correct you markup everything should work fine.